# Garmin edge 510

Tags: bike-computer, garmin

I've had this Garmin since December and all of a sudden it's not reading cadence and speed.

I've tried resetting it but I think that made it worse. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you check the battery on the speed/cadence sensor? Can you be more specific about what solutions you have tried?

Comment: Yeah, the manual for this device steps through how to pair them, what you should see on the sensor re LEDs etc. How much of that have you tried and what were the results? It would be strange indeed if, having paid a lot of money for the device, you hadn't read the User Manual along the way.

Answer (score 2):

Garmin 510 uses ANT+ to communicate to the add-on devices.
I would remove and re-pair the devices first to see if they are actually seeing each other first.

The speed and cadence sensor should pair as a single device and not speed and cadence separately.

Answer (score 0):

I would try another speed cadence to see it works with that or try yours with another Garmin (friend?). Sometimes the sensor shifts a bit; I found that it has to be really close to the pedal to function properly.

Folks in bike shops are often very friendly/helpful with such things. The battery could also be an issue.  ~510 owner.

Comment: Going from memory I think Garmin say that the sensor needs to be within 5mm of the magnet. That sort of ballpark anyway. But it would be strange for the device to drop both speed and cadence data - normally if you knock the sensor it will end up further away from one magnet (so you lose that data) but closer to the other magnet (so you still get that data). Battery life should be in the order of a year.

Answer (score 0):

With my ant+ sensor it got flakey then stopped working.  The cause was damage to the wire between the little pedal sensor and the blockier wheel sensor - I must have caught it on my foot.

**Answer** Don't assume its the Garmin unit.

Do you have another ant+ device to test?   I found a cheap ant+ Heart Rate Monitor is more useful than the cadence information.